# Tags: Cleaning and clean - Do we need both?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have a [clean](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean) tag and a [cleaning](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) tag.

Do we need both?

Answer (score 4):

No, we don't need both.  Retag [clean](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean) question to [cleaning](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning), and create a synonym.